# How did this character know that Violet was in danger in her sleep?

Tags: empyrean-series, fourth-wing

In *Fourth Wing* (the first book in the Empyrean series), the main character, Violet Sorrengail

> bonds with Tairn

A couple of week after the threshing (an event where a dragon potentially 'bonds' with a cadet), Violet goes to sleep and dreams of her father talking to her in the archives. During her dream she hears a strong deep voice beckoning her to wake up.

It turns out that the voice belongs to

> Tairn,

warning her of an attack on her life whilst she sleeps.

But there is no indication about how

> Tairn

knew she was in danger.

**How did this character know that Violet was in danger in her sleep?**

Comment: "Hello. My name is Violet, and I was born into a world my author may not understand."